# Adding component that runs a simple js script to create-react-app app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

Hi This seems like something that should be simple but no matter how many searches I do i can't seem to find a clear answer or i'm just fundamentally misunderstanding something. I want to add a simple component.

I have a simple react app here is the app.js

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import fortune from './fortune.js' ;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Wowsersssss
        </p>
      
      <button onclick="myFortune()">Fortune</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and a simple component that I am importing

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
function fortune() {
  const message = () => {
    alert("Hello");
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={message}>Click Here</button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<fortune />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How do I now insert that into the app.js?

I'd really appreciate if someone could show me where to add it in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the code the wrong way round. `App` should be the component that's attached to the main react element in the DOM (generally), and then you import new components. Also, new components should have names written in [Pascal Case](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Pascal-case-vs-camel-case-Whats-the-difference) otherwise you'll get errors.

So here I've created a `MyFortune` component, and it gets imported into `App`.

```js
function MyFortune() {

  function message() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }

  return (
    <button
      onClick={message}
    >Click Here
    </button>
  );

}

// export default MyFortune;

// import MyFortune from './MyFortune';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <p>Wowsersssss</p>
        <MyFortune />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the component itself so that you can Import it.
You need to Capitalize your Function Name as well for the component.

```
import React from 'react'

function Fortune(){
  function clicked(){
   console.log('clicked')
   }
return(
 <button onClick={clicked}>I am a button</button>
)
}

export default Fortune


*//////////////*

import Fortune from './Fortune' 
//Assuming they're in the same folder level

//You can Display it by Declaring it inside the <> just like meta tags do
<Fortune />
```

You can add a onlick function towards the component but the function must be above the return statement if complex or can be a one-liner code on the JSX return section. Take note that React uses pascal Case on these functions when Called like onClick not onclick, className not className .

Comment: Yep, sorry typo.